# What is the correct formatting pattern for this String format?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, zoneddatetime, threetenbp

I am getting a DateTimeParseException when trying to convert a String to a ZonedDateTime with threeten. I am not sure what the correct formatting pattern is for this String format?
2014-04-16T00:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]. Can someone tell me how the correct pattern is?

On a sitenote: Is there some page or some resource somewhere where I can look such things up without having to reconstruct it by myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Asking for off site resources is not allowed on SO: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Absolutely off topic @Rob please revise my question and reply accordingly to what I was actually asking, thanks a lot

Comment: I found what I needed, it is a duplicate of this topic on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658034/converting-zoneddatetime-to-string?rq=1

Comment: Since you confirm it is off topic and a duplicate, you should delete this altogether.

Comment: Your first comment states "Absolutely off topic". Your second comment states "it is a duplicate of..." which makes it, in SO vernacular, "off topic". I only quoted what you said. And our question is up for deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No formatter needed:** Your format is the default format for a `ZonedDateTime`. `ZonedDateTime` both parses and prints this format as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

```
    String s = "2014-04-16T00:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]";
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(s);
    System.out.println("Parsed into " + zdt);
```

Output:

> Parsed into 2014-04-16T00:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]

The format is extended from ISO 8601 format. ISO 8601 would be `2014-04-16T00:00+02:00` only, so includes the UTC offset but not the time zone. The developers of java.time extended it to include the time zone ID.

**If you want a formatter:** If you have a special reason for wanting a formatter, maybe you need to pass one to a method or you just wish to make it explicit which format you expect, one is built in: `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`. So you still don’t need to write any format pattern string.

**Where to find this information?** It’s in the documentation of the classes of java.time. See the documentation links below.

**Your own code:** Thank you for providing your own code in the comment under this answer. For other readers I am repeating it here, formatted for readability.

```
fun parseZonedDateTimeToString(date: ZonedDateTime): String {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME.format(date)
}

fun parseStringToZonedDateTime(dateString: String): ZonedDateTime {
     return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)
}
```

**Links**

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- Documentation links:

  - The one-arg [`ZonedDateTime.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) specifying “a text string such as `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`”
  - [`ZonedDateTime.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString()) promising “a `String`, such as `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`”
  - [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with the built-in formatters as well as the pattern letters used in format pattern strings
  - [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME), “The ISO-like date-time formatter that formats or parses a date-time with offset and zone, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]'.”
  - Since the links above are to the documentation of the Java 10 versions of the classes, which is not always identical to the documentation  of the backport, here is the documentation of [ThreeTen backport 1.4.2 API](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/index.html), under which you will find all of the above items too.

Comment: This is valuable information on how to use ZonedDateTime thank you! Especially interesting for me is the different doc links with different methods. As you said, ThreeTen backport is slightly different.

Comment: I used the following two methods to convert from ZonedDateTime to String as well as the other way round:

    fun parseZonedDateTimeToString(date: ZonedDateTime): String {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME.format(date)
    }

    

fun parseStringToZonedDateTime(dateString: String): ZonedDateTime {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)
    }

This works perfectly fine and does not really deviate from the java.time classes ;) 
Thanks!